# Trying to install Chrome

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, dependencies

I'm running Ubuntu with crouton on a Chromebook. I'm trying to install Chrome and I keep getting a bunch of errors which can be seen in the image bellow. If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, provide text outputs rather than screenshots. It helps finding the question and improves formatting. Thanks

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` will solve it.

Comment: @Pilot6 That command just uninstalls the incomplete download. Chrome is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? What is the Ubuntu version? Did you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Note, Crouton is not Ubuntu. It uses the Chrome-OS kernel.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814))? Thanks.

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -a` and `apt-cache policy google-chome-stable libstdc++6 lsb-base`?

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert but you can simply download .deb file from: https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

And then run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This will may help as well for resolving dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: That page gives me a 404 in Firefox.

Comment: Then go to this one: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/

And then download from there.

Comment: I got it to download, ran the first command and got this 'Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
(precise)charlesragland@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  google-chrome-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 190 MB disk space will be freed.'

Comment: @CharlesRagland Try updating repository list by `sudo apt-get update` then update OS by `sudo apt-get upgrade` & then give it a try.

Comment: I figured it out. Crouton is using 12.04 and Chrome no longer supports that. Thanks for the help!